# When querying MongoDB using DBeaver, what's the right syntax for filtering by date?

Tags: mongodb-query, dbeaver

I recently discovered that DBeaver can connect to MongoDB.  My next discovery was that DBeaver expects SQL-like queries instead of the JavaScript-like queries I use with the mongo command line client.  I've been unable to find any good documentation on the syntax I should be using, so I've been learning by trial and error.  I need some help filtering query results by date.

I have a collection named `tasks`.  Each object in the collection has a `startedAt` attribute that holds a timestamp.

This query gives me lots of results using the command line client: `db.tasks.find({startedAt:{$gt:ISODate("2017-03-03")}});`

I'm guessing the syntax in DBeaver should be something like this: `select * from tasks where startedAt > '2017-03-03';`

But, I'm doing something wrong because I don't get any results in DBeaver unless I drop the `where` clause.  What's the right way?